# MMAL Raspberry Pi Speed

Tags: raspbian, python, camera, raspicam, mmal

Does anyone know if there is a way to improve the speed of taking photos with raspistill? I have a Python program which basically calls "subprocess.call" - I've noticed that the speed of such an operation is about 2.7 seconds, is there a way to improve this? I've read online that raspistill isn't that fast maybe 2-3 fps, but with speeds of 2.7 seconds that seems extremely slow. One alternative I am considering doing is running it in timelapse mode maybe this will improve the speed? (I am using this for motion detection so I take a photo compare it to the previous one and detect changes via Python - maybe there is a way to use the video option of mmal to output stills if possible?) Any advice would be appreciated.

Here is a link to a snippet of the code where this function is working : https://gist.github.com/eWizardII/6756689

Answer (score 1):

You have `-t 1000` in there, which will wait 1 second before taking the photo. `-t 0` will reduce the call by 1 second

Comment: Thanks - so I added the delay because without it I was getting black images like there wasn't a long enough exposure time or something is there a way around that issue?